# Adding a specifically chosen number in a For loop to work out the total mutiplies number Java

Tags: java

```
public class totalCount {                                       
  public static void main(String[] args){                                       
    int total = 0;                                      
    for (int i=1; i<=100;i++){                                      
      if(i%2==0){                                       
        System.out.println(i);                                      
      } else if(i%4==0){                                        
        System.out.println(i);                                      
      }                                                                         
      total +=i;                                        
    }                                       
    System.out.println(total);                                      
  }                                     
}
```

I am in a bit of confusion, I tried to create a for loop function to specifically pick out the mutiplies of 2 and 4 up to 100 and then finding the sum of the number. However, I am unable to find the sum of the number as I can't seem to add up the total number generated by the for loop. How do I find the total sum?

Comment: Every multiple of 4 is also a multiple of 2.

Comment: Oh okay understood - solved

Answer (score 2):

First of all you only need `i % 2 == 0` as anything divisible by four is also divisible by two. Second you need to move the line `total += i;` into the `if` statement:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){                                      
   if(i % 2 == 0){                                       
      System.out.println(i);                                                     
      total += i;                                        
   }                                                                           
}   
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using Lambda

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TotalCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] total = new int[2];
        final int START = 1;
        final int END = 100;

        // loop from 1 through 100. endExclusive so need to use END + 1
        IntStream.range(START, END + 1)
                .filter(number -> number % 2 == 0)
                .forEach(multipleOf2 -> total[0] += multipleOf2);
        IntStream.range(START, END + 1)
                .filter(number -> number % 4 == 0)
                .forEach(multipleOf4 -> total[1] += multipleOf4);

        System.out.println("Sum of multiples of 2: " + total[0]);
        System.out.println("Sum of multiples of 4: " + total[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: With the stream, reduce, then assign the reduction output to the proper total, rather than constantly writing to the same location in memory. Using reduction here permits simple parallelisation.